# How to add code without using init SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I’m defining mainArray as a global variable and have this in my init function:

```
init(post: Post, post2: [PostById]) {
    self.post = post
    self.post2 = post2

     if let posty = post {
       mainArray = self.post2.filter { i in i.album_id == posty.id }
        print("mainArray \(mainArray)")
       }
}
```

Which I’m using in a List like this:

```
var body: some View {

             VStack {
                Text("Title: ").bold()
                    + Text("\(post.title)")
                ImageView(withURL: "http://localhost:8000/\(post.path.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20"))")
                    Text("Description: ").bold()
                        + Text("\(post.description)")
                List(mainArray) { post in
                    Text("\(post.name ?? "title")")

                }


        }
```

The problem is I have to use the init function like this in my ContentView: 
`NavigationLink(destination: Album.init(post: post, post2: self.model2.postsById))` which calls my init function on my ContentView which I don’t want instead of doing `Album(post: post, post2: self.model2.postsById)`.

My question is how I can put the

```
if let posty = post {
       mainArray = self.post2.filter { i in i.album_id == posty.id }
        print("mainArray \(mainArray)")
       }
```

outside of my init function as well as not declare mainArray as a global variable and still use it in my List?

Comment: Album.init(...) and Album(...) are equal ...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to filter when creating the List, then you don't need the mainArray at all

```
List(self.post2.filter { i in i.album_id == posty.id }) { post in
    Text("\(post.name ?? "title")")
}
```

Comment: I love this answer but for some reason it's not showing anything. Maybe post2 doesn't have the data in it yet since it's getting data from my database.

Comment: how would I make sure post2 has data before I use it?

Comment: @DDavis25 That is really a complete different question but maybe you can use a closure to load your view once all the data has arrived but I don't know your code structure so I can't know what is best. I suggest you create a new question for this since it will be a problem no matter how you solve this issue.

Comment: I asked the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60837104/how-to-make-sure-data-in-variable-is-loaded-before-using-it